# Swift. Why singleton lost data?

Tags: swift, singleton

Why my data is lost in singleton? Please take a look:

```
class YtDataManager {
    static var shared_instance = YtDataManager()

    let apiKey = /*...*/
    let /*...*/
    var channelData = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
    var videosArray = [[NSObject:AnyObject]]()

    var playlistId: String { return self.channelData["playlistId"] as! String}
    var urlStringForRequestChannelDetails: String { return String("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails,snippet&forUsername=\(self./*ChannelName*/)&key=\(self.apiKey)") }
    var urlStringForRequestChannelVideos: String { return String("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=\(self.playlistId)&key=\(self.apiKey)") }
   func fn1() { /*...*/ }
   func fn2() { /*...*/ }

// class definition continue...
```

Look, from one function(`fn1`) I'm writing data to channelData:

```
//...
self.channelData["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
self.channelData["playlistId"] = ((firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! [NSObject:AnyObject])["relatedPlaylists"] as! [NSObject:AnyObject])["uploads"]
//...
```

and so on... From second function(`fn2`), I'm reading data:

```
//...
let targetURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.urlStringForRequestChannelVideos)
//...
```

Hence `urlStringForRequestChannelVideos` is computational property it uses `playlistId` (look code above).

Here I was surprised about emptiness of channedData from second function(I saw it in Debug mode, also I printed it's count to stdout outside of function). Why????

```
class YtFeedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

            YtDataManager.shared_instance.fn1()
            print(YtDataManager.shared_instance.channelData.count) //0
            YtDataManager.shared_instance.fn2() //errorness
        }

        self.navigationItem.title = "YouTube feed"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: I'd bet that your fn1 () is called asynchronously. Set breakpoints to see when code gets executed.

Comment: yep, seems you're right. I just forgot about async request! Sadly right now I broke my code and wasn't commit them before so I try your suggestion later.